# Getting issue while installing Backbone-Require-Boilerplate

Tags: npm, backbone-boilerplate

I am new to npm. So, simply i have followed the steps they mentioned in "Getting Started" topic in https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Backbone-Require-Boilerplate page.

At the step 6, on `npm install`, i am getting the following error,

```
11578 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry LICENSE.BSD
11579 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'LICENSE.BSD', 438, 420 ]
11580 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry dist/lodash.compat.js
11581 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'dist/lodash.compat.js', 438, 420 ]
11582 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry bin/r.js
11583 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'bin/r.js', 438, 420 ]
11584 silly gunzTarPerm extractEntry dist/lodash.compat.min.js
11585 silly gunzTarPerm modified mode [ 'dist/lodash.compat.min.js', 438, 420 ]
11586 error Error: ENOENT, lstat 'E:\Backbone-Require-Boilerplate-master\node_modules\karma-coverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\text.js'
11587 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
11587 error including the npm and node versions, at:
11587 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
11588 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
11589 error command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
11590 error cwd E:\Backbone-Require-Boilerplate-master
11591 error node -v v0.10.26
11592 error npm -v 1.4.3
11593 error path E:\Backbone-Require-Boilerplate-master\node_modules\karma-coverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\text.js
11594 error fstream_path E:\Backbone-Require-Boilerplate-master\node_modules\karma-coverage\node_modules\istanbul\lib\report\text.js
11595 error fstream_type File
11596 error fstream_class FileWriter
11597 error code ENOENT
11598 error errno 34
11599 error fstream_stack C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
11599 error fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
11600 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

Why this issue comes and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't installed the [git](http://git-scm.com/) yet while trying these things. That's why i have got this error. My issue gets resolved after installed the git.

They didn't mentioned anything about **git** on https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Backbone-Require-Boilerplate. Download the git from: http://git-scm.com/ and try install the npm package after git installation.

Thanks.